# Using DynamicMap() and ignore null source value

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I'm using `Mapper.DynamicMap()` inside a generic method and would like to, without using `.CreateMap()`, ignore some any source values that are null. Is this even possible?

Comment: Do you mean if you had a list of "source" objects and some were null, you don't want a list of mapped "destination" objects with some nulls -- you just want the non-null source objects mapped?

Comment: Exactly. For example: if I have a Source object with Name and SSN, and a Destination object with the same property, if any of those properties are null in the Source object i don't want them mapped in the Destination object. Why you may ask? I don't any properties that are already set in the Destination object to be overwritten by null values.

Comment: use this http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/ if you like dynamic/convention based mapping

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you want all source properties with null values to be ignored you could use:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceType, DestinationType>()
                    .ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition(srs => !srs.IsSourceValueNull));
```

Otherwise, you can do something similar for each member. This will get quit tedious if there are a large number of properties.

Comment: Any way to do this with DynamicMap rather than CreateMap?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with *DataMember property* in destination type `[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]` add this in the destination `DTO`