# AutoMapper IsSourceValueNull Condition doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, automapper

I'm using this [Using DynamicMap() and ignore null source value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704512) approach to make the mapper ignore properties with NULL values on the source, but this doesn't appear to work in version **2.1.267.0** (current).

Here's my mapping config:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<PersonDTO, Person>().ForAllMembers(
    opt => opt.Condition(srs => !srs.IsSourceValueNull));
```

Here's my test:

```
// Arrange   
var Person = new Person { FirstName = "Bruce", Surname = "Lee"};
var PersonDto = new PersonDTO { FirstName = "Jet", Surname = null };

// Act
Mapper.Map(PersonDto, Person);

// Assert
Assert.AreEqual("Jet", Person.FirstName); // Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<Jet>. Actual:<Bruce>. 
Assert.AreEqual("Lee", Person.Surname, "Surname field with NULL value should not have been mapped");
```

Does it work for you? And if so, can you spot the problem in my code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is supposed to be fixed in AutoMapper version 2.2