# Populate POCO with non-default values from another POCO in C#

Tags: c#, automapper

I have an external API that sends objects in XML. On every update, the API sends only fields that have changed since last update. Is there a library that could update existing POCO instance with non-default or changed values from a new one?

I used AutoMapper in another project, but it either does not support such method or I am blind and cannot understand how to use it for this purpose. I know that I could create a very sophisticated manual mappings with AutoMapper, but probably there is an automatic way using dynamic mappings?

Comment: I'm fairly sure the `CreateMap()` with `opt => opt.Contition` mentioned in [this duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704512/automapper-using-dynamicmap-and-ignore-null-source-value) does what you want. If not, @ping me and I'll reopen.

Comment: It definitely doesn't answer the question about default or changed values (only `null`s). But this is probably the right direction. Unfortunately no one will be able to paste the right snippets, which answer the question, if this is the solution :)

Comment: Show a [mcve] then please. Class definitions, source data, incoming data, what the end result should look like and the mappings you've tried.

Comment: @CodeCaster yes, this works, and I posted minimal, complete and passing unit tests below. Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered making an object that takes an original POCO object and encapsulates the members (boot strap)?  Then your new object (encapsulating object) will except the XML and update the values accordingly?  This will still be a POCO object, but not a DTO object - but the source object could be DTO.  I used this method of binding Silverlight object back in the day.

Comment: @DanAndrews it would be too much coupling. And XML is such an $%&*( technology that I would rather hide it far away in a hope that on some nice day there is no more of it.

Comment: @V.B. Very well and agreed, it would couple the objects together.  It worked well for my MVVM application however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggested [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704512/automapper-using-dynamicmap-and-ignore-null-source-value) led to the right direction. There are some gotchas with equality of `object` types, but linked answer was the key.

Below are fully reproducible unit tests:

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;
using AutoMapper;

namespace MyTests {
    [TestFixture]
    public class AutomappingTests {

        public class IncrementalPOCO
        {
            public int ValueType { get; set; }
            public string RefernceType { get; set; }
        }

        private Func<IncrementalPOCO> getOriginal = () => new IncrementalPOCO()
        {
            ValueType = 123,
            RefernceType = "original text"
        };

        private IncrementalPOCO updateValue = new IncrementalPOCO()
        {
            ValueType = 456
        };

        private IncrementalPOCO updateText = new IncrementalPOCO()
        {
            RefernceType = "updated text"
        };

        private IncrementalPOCO updateWithDefault = new IncrementalPOCO()
        {
            ValueType = 0,
            RefernceType = null
        };


        public static bool Always(object value)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public static bool IsDefault(Type type, object value) {
            if (type.IsValueType) {
                return Activator.CreateInstance(type).Equals(value);
            }
            return null == value;
        }

        public static bool AreDifferent(Type type, object source, object destination) {
            if (type.IsValueType) {
                return !source.Equals(destination);
            }
            return !ReferenceEquals(source, destination);
        }

        [Test]
        public void CouldUpdateValues() {
            // Updates all properties
            var original = getOriginal();
            var map = Mapper.CreateMap<IncrementalPOCO, IncrementalPOCO>();

            map.ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition(srs => Always(srs.SourceValue))); // just for overload resolution, `true` doesn't work

            Mapper.Map<IncrementalPOCO, IncrementalPOCO>(updateValue, original);
            Assert.AreEqual(null, original.RefernceType);
            Assert.AreEqual(updateValue.ValueType, original.ValueType);

        }

        [Test]
        public void CouldUpdateNonDefaultValues()
        {
            // should work for value types and reference types (nulls)
            var original = getOriginal();
            var map = Mapper.CreateMap<IncrementalPOCO, IncrementalPOCO>();
            // NB != or simple equility won't work
            map.ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition(srs => !(IsDefault(srs.SourceType, srs.SourceValue))) );

            Mapper.Map<IncrementalPOCO, IncrementalPOCO>(updateValue, original);
            Assert.AreEqual("original text", original.RefernceType);
            Assert.AreEqual(updateValue.ValueType, original.ValueType);

            original = getOriginal();
            Mapper.Map<IncrementalPOCO, IncrementalPOCO>(updateText, original);
            Assert.AreEqual("updated text", original.RefernceType);
            Assert.AreEqual(123, original.ValueType);

            // this mapping should not change the original because all new values are default
            original = getOriginal();
            Mapper.Map<IncrementalPOCO, IncrementalPOCO>(updateWithDefault, original);
            Assert.AreEqual("original text", original.RefernceType);
            Assert.AreEqual(123, original.ValueType);
        }

        [Test]
        public void CouldUpdateChangedValues() {
            // should update value types when new value is a default one, but different from origin
            var original = getOriginal();
            var map = Mapper.CreateMap<IncrementalPOCO, IncrementalPOCO>();
            // NB != or simple equility won't work
            map.ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition(srs => (AreDifferent(srs.SourceType, srs.SourceValue, srs.DestinationValue))));

            Mapper.Map<IncrementalPOCO, IncrementalPOCO>(updateValue, original);
            Assert.AreEqual(null, original.RefernceType);
            Assert.AreEqual(updateValue.ValueType, original.ValueType);

            original = getOriginal();
            Mapper.Map<IncrementalPOCO, IncrementalPOCO>(updateText, original);
            Assert.AreEqual("updated text", original.RefernceType);
            Assert.AreEqual(0, original.ValueType);

            // this mapping will change the original because all new values are default but different from original
            original = getOriginal();
            Mapper.Map<IncrementalPOCO, IncrementalPOCO>(updateWithDefault, original);
            Assert.AreEqual(null, original.RefernceType);
            Assert.AreEqual(0, original.ValueType);
        }

    }
}
```